# IBM HTTP server and ldap authorization

Tags: ldap, ibmhttpserver

I have an IBM http server v 5.3
I have to set up authorization through ldap. I find CN object by attribute. If CN not in current OU, I can't find it, but if CN in current OU there is no problem. So I think http server searches only in current Ldap entry. How to set up config file of http server to search in subtree too ?

Comment: Example ldapsearch with a subtree scope that works vs. your configuration?

IHS 5.3 / DGW apparently always does scope=subtree searches. But it's unclear that your data is really 'under" your search base

Comment: I forgot to tell that i'm using Http server on z/OS platform. UserSearchBase                           
                    GroupSearchBase 
                    GroupMemberAttrs                                       
                    UserNameFilter 
                    GroupNameFilter. And these derectives used in config

Comment: I have a root - DC=my,DC=super,DC=company. Under that I have a seversal OU and user which I use to authorize on LDAP server located in that OU. User which I want to find located in that OU too. My settings: ServerDN is "domain\authuser", UserSearchBase is "DC=my,DC=super,DC=company", UserNameFilter is "(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=%v1)" and I see an error in log..... in order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection. How to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.
By default, our server redirects requests to another root DC (DC=XXXXX,DC=my,DC=super,DC=company). So, I found the directive Referralls Off and put it in config file.